# type 'object' cannot be made the primary key

Tags: react-native, realm

I am not able to specify a `type` as my `primaryKey` in a Realm schema`.

Here are my schema types:

```
class EventKey extends Realm.Object{}
EventKey.schema = {
  name: 'EventKey',
  properties: {
    rideid: { type: 'int', indexed: true },
    ts: {type: 'int', indexed: true}
  }
};
class Events extends Realm.Object{}
Events.schema = {
  name: 'Events',
  primaryKey: 'eventKey',
  properties: {
    eventKey: {type: 'EventKey'},
    devid: { type: 'int'},
    lat: {type: 'float'},
    lng: {type: 'float'},
    alt: {type: 'float'},
    spd: {type: 'float'},
    brg: {type: 'float'},
    hepe: {type: 'float'},
    vepe: {type: 'float'},
    ang: {type: 'float'},
    temp: {type: 'float'},
    motion: {type: 'bool'},
    ignition: {type: 'bool'},
    mainPower: {type: 'bool'},
    relayState: {type: 'bool'},
  }
};
```

I want to use type `EventKey` in type `Events` as `primaryKey`. but it throws an exception saying:

```
Schema validation failed due to the following errors:
- Property 'Events.eventKey' of type 'object' cannot be made the primary key.
```

In other words, I want to create `UNIQUE_INDEX` in realm, which will prevent any duplicate entry against a `rideid and ts`. How to solve this?

Comment: You could concatenate them together into a string and then use that as primary key

Comment: yes, But is that the only way?

Comment: yup, pretty much.